# hive external table needing write access

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs

I am trying to load a dataset stored on HDFS (textfile) into hive for analysis.
I am using create external table as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL table myTable(field1 STRING...) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/user/myusername/datasetlocation';
```

This works fine, but it requires **write access** to the hdfs location. Why is that?

In general, what is the right way to load text data to which I do not have write access? is there a 'read-only' external table type?

Edit: I noticed [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-335) on hive regarding the question. It does not seem to have been resolved.

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538487/why-does-the-user-need-write-permission-on-the-location-of-external-hive-table
(but no answer..)

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue from back in 2009 -

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-335

Doesn't look like there is any way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution to this, but as a workaround I've discovered that

`CREATE TEMPORARY EXTERNAL TABLE`

works without write permissions, the difference being the table (but not the underlying data) will disappear after your session.

Comment: too bad partition columns are not supported on temporary tables

Comment: What happens to data stored in table after session ? Because i think external table store data in HDFS and when table gets deleted only metadata deleted. in that case, there will be lots of data persist on HDFS.

Comment: The data is untouched (edited the post to say this), indeed the point was you can do this without write access to the data so it isn't necessarily possible to do anything to it.

Comment: This does not work in my enivornment, still says I have no permission for operation CREATETABLE although I have read access in that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Partially answering my own question:

Indeed it seems not to be resolved by hive at this moment. But here is an interesting fact: hive does not require write access to the files themselves, but only to the folder. For example, you could have a folder with permissions `777`, but the files within it, which are accessed by hive, can stay read-only, e.g. `644`.

Answer (score 1):

If you require write access to hdfs files give
hadoop dfs -chmod 777 /folder name

this means your giving all access permissions to that particular file.

Comment: This is exactly what the question is about. I don't want to (and sometimes can't) get write access to the file. Usually the data is the outcome of another process, of which I have no control. 
I have only read access to that dataset, because, well, I only need to read it.

Comment: Ok i understood. I have tested the hive external query in which the hdfs file does not have write permissions. It is executing for me. What i have done is i gave permissions to hadoop storage folder. First check whether ur hadoop folder is having full permissions or not. If not having give permissions and check the query, it should work that time.